# Multidatespicker: Disable dates from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I would like to use the following method, but use a list instead of a couple of dates.

```
addDisabledDates: [today.setDate(1), today.setDate(3)]
```

This is the code for my calender:

> $("#ExceptionDates").multiDatesPicker({
>
> ```
>     defaultDate: "+1w",
>     firstDay: 1,
>     dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
>     numberOfMonths: 1,
>     **addDisabledDates: ['06/19/2012','06/20/2012'],** (NOT working)
>     onSelect: function ()
>     {
>         var dates = $("#ExceptionDates").multiDatesPicker('getDates');
>         var html = '';
>         $.each(dates, function (i, val)
>         {
>             html += '<input type="text" name="Dates" value="' + val + '">';
>         });
>
>         $("#SelectedDates").html(html);
>     }
> });
> ```

This is the method to get the dates:

```
var getSelectedExceptionDates = function(callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Route/GetSelectedExceptionDates/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response)
        {
            callback(response);
        },
        error: function (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

};

var callback = function (dates)
{
    $.each(dates, function (i, date)
    {
        var splitDate = date.split('.');

    var day = splitDate[0];
    var month = splitDate[1];
    var year = splitDate[2];

    console.log(splitDate);
    console.log(new Date(year, (parseInt(month)-1).toString(), day));
});

};

getSelectedExceptionDates(callback);
```

And this is what i get out by inspecting the site now:

["12", "11", "2009"] General.js:101
Thu Nov 12 2009 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)

Theres two different types cause im logging both atm.

Any ideas how i can insert my list of dates into the addDisabledDates method?

**EDIT: I got it working!**

```
var callback = function (dates)
    {
        var date_ary = new Array();
        $.each(dates, function (i, date)
        {
            var splitDate = date.split('.');

            var day = splitDate[0];
            var month = splitDate[1];
            var year = splitDate[2];
            date_ary.push(new Date(month + "/" + day + "/" + year));
        });

        console.log(date_ary);

        $("#ExceptionDates").multiDatesPicker({
            minDate: 0,
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            firstDay: 1,
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
            addDisabledDates: date_ary,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function ()
            {
                var dates = $("#ExceptionDates").multiDatesPicker('getDates');
                var html = '';
                $.each(dates, function (i, val)
                {
                    html += '<input type="text" name="Dates" value="' + val + '">';
                });

                $("#SelectedDates").html(html);
            }
        });
    };
    getSelectedExceptionDates(callback);

var getSelectedExceptionDates = function (callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Route/GetSelectedExceptionDates/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response)
        {
            callback(response);
        },
        error: function (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#ExceptionDates").multiDatesPicker({

defaultDate: "+1w",
firstDay: 1,
dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
numberOfMonths: 1,
addDisabledDates: getSelectedExceptionDates(callback),
onSelect: function ()
  {
    var dates = $("#ExceptionDates").multiDatesPicker('getDates');
    var html = '';
    $.each(dates, function (i, val)
    {
        html += '<input type="text" name="Dates" value="' + val + '">';
    });

    $("#SelectedDates").html(html);
  }
 });

var getSelectedExceptionDates = function(callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Route/GetSelectedExceptionDates/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response)
        {
            return callback(response);
        },
        error: function (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

};
var callback = function (dates)
{
    var date_ary = new Array();
    $.each(dates, function (i, date)
    {
        var splitDate = date.split('.');

        var day = splitDate[0];
        var month = splitDate[1];
        var year = splitDate[2];
        date_ary.push(month + "/" + day + "/" + year );

    });
    return date_ary;
};

getSelectedExceptionDates(callback);
```

Comment: Accepted the answer, but i did have to do some changes to get it working.

Comment: Glad.. I did not try the code out before typing.. may have some issues.. but gave a rough cut to you