# I place a HTML class definition in style tag and then use it in beforeShowDay and it is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following:

```
$("<style>")
    .prop("type", "text/css")
    .html("\
#markDates {\
    color: #FF0000;\
}")
    .appendTo("head");
```

and then I call this class in:

```
 $('#multidatepicker').multiDatesPicker({
        //onClose: function (value, date) {
        //    //debugger;
        //    date.dpDiv.find('.ui-state-default').css('background-color', 'rgb(153, 204, 153)')
        //}, 
        numberOfMonths: [3, 4],
        //addDisabledDates: HolidayList,
        addDates: getHolidays(),
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        //    console.log('dateIn?', $.inArray(date, HolidayList));
            if ($.inArray(date, HolidayList) !== -1) {
                $("td").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
                return [true, "markDates" , "This is a holiiday"];
            }
            else {
                return [true];
            }
        }
    });
```

and when I run it and then inspect the element of date that is highlighted the following is discovered:

```
<td class=" ui-state-highlight undefined " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="0" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">1</a></td>
```

Why is markDates undefined? I have tried to:

```
removeClass("ui-state-highlight").addClass("markDates")
```

with the same result.

Comment: `#markDates` in the first script is an `id`. while `removeClass("ui-state-highlight").addClass("markDates") ` is adding the class `markDates`

Comment: You have commented out the last closing bracket `//}` for `beforeShowDay`

Comment: @Filipe Thanks for the change.  I made the appropriate change and still showing as undefined in the element.

Comment: Also "This is a holiday" does not show as tooltip.

Comment: It's probably hitting the else part of your `if ... else` block and trying to set the class to be the second index of the return value of `beforeShowDay`.  That is undefined.  I bet if you change `return [true];` to `return [true, 'noMarkDates'];`, it would no longer be undefined, but it would have noMarkDates as its class.

Comment: @JosephMarikle That was it thanks.  Now to figure out how to make highlighted date red and why the else is working instead of the if.

Comment: @m.rice Can you console.log the contents of `HolidayList` and add it to the question please?

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined because it's hitting your `else` statement within `beforeShowDay`.  This method must take the second index of the return value and use it as the class for the day item.  changing `return [true];` to `return [true, 'noMarkDates'];` corrects the undefined issue, but doesn't really solve the problem because we do want to highlight particular days.  I think it's an issue with `HolidayList`.  `beforeShowDay` uses a date object for the `date` variable.  You're trying to see if that same date object is in an array of dates.  There is (at least in my opinion) a high chance that this will result in faulty data due to inconsistent formatting or too much information in the date objects (the date object includes hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds when all you want is the day, month, and year).  You can probably correct this by formatting your date first.

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
  // first get a consistent format for your date
  var d = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', date);
  // then compare it against an array of similarly formatted date strings
  if ($.inArray(d, ["01-23-2016","03-17-2016","03-16-2016"]) !== -1) {
    return [true, "markDates" , "This is a holiiday"];
  }
  else {
    return [true, 'noMarkDates'];
  }
}
```

The result is that the correct dates are highlighted: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/1gr6237q/1/

Also, note that I used the style `.markDates { background: red; }`.  Yours uses an ID instead of a class (the difference of `.` and `#`).  Please use a class instead.

*Got the `formatDate` bit from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28852510/854246*