# Disabling Dates in jquery datepicker from recordset

Tags: jquery, sql-server, vbscript, jquery-ui-datepicker, ado

this is my first post so please pardon me for any mistakes

Im building a simple **reservation system** as college project for a firm, Its in classic asp due to an old server already running there.

Ive Managed to use a jquery date picker found here
[MultiDatePicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)

Now the problem is even after continuous searching on similar threads i have no success in passing dates to  addDisabledDates function

Problem is i need to **pass in date**s into this function from my **database's Reservation Table** so that i can block it from being further selected.

This is what code for connection looks like`

```
    Dim sm ,String
    Con.open
    set recobj = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    sm = "Select BO_Date From ERND_Reservation Where SD_Id='"& request.querystring("Stall") & "'"
    recobj.open sm, Con, ,3

    String = recobj.GetString(, ,,"','", "")
```

I'm using getString Method to populate a list of strings from recordset, The output for whick looks like this

2016-01-25','2016-02-05','2016-02-06','

Also this is the code for MultiDatepicker

```
<script>

    $(function() {

    var today = new Date()
    $('#simplest-usage').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    addDisabledDates: ['2016-01-25','2016-02-05','2016-02-06']

    });
    });
</script>
```

**I need to somehow pass the String from my recordset directly in multidatepickers addDisabledDates Function**

Any Help in doing so will be highly appreciated by any approach whatsoever

Thank You

Comment: I am no help with the date picker object you are working with but...I know this is a college project but you need to learn immediately if not sooner how to parameterize your queries. The way you take a query string value and execute that against your database is a textbook example of sql injection. Do your client a favor and fix that glaring security problem before you turn this loose on their system.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852426/multidatespicker-adddisableddates

Comment: Hello Sean, Thank you for the advise as u can see its the first time im doing something like this so im trying to keep its complexity to the minimum however im aware of sql injection and i hope sooner ill be in a position to prevent it without banging my head too much

Comment: Hello prola ive seen that thread before however its not helping me with passing my string into multidatepicker

Comment: Do NOT put off learning how to prevent sql injection until you have time. The reality is that you will not go back and fix it. It takes barely a few seconds more to parameterize your queries when you write them. Even if it the time magically presents itself later (which it never does) it will take a lot longer to fix it. Just do it right the first time and it is a non-issue.

Comment: There are literally thousands of examples of doing this the right way. Once you do it you will see how simple it really is. https://www.google.com/search?q=classic+asp+parameterized+query+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: thanks again +1 for the advise surely security should be at d top most of the list also while im on sql injection can someone help out on the problem im facing with datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys ive found a solution to my problem and the datepicker is now dynamically disabling dates from sql server 2008 database

To Do this i had to use bits of javascript and vbscript together, thanks to a guy named old padent whose answer im referring to from some other forums

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var DisabledDays = new Array();//javascript array
 <%
 'Now we r in asp code
 Dim index : index = 0
 Do Until recobj.EOF
        Response.Write "DisabledDays[" & index & "]='" & recobj(0) & "';" & vbNewLine
        recobj.MoveNext
        index = index + 1
Loop
'End of asp
%>
//end of javascript
</script>
```

Here whats done is asp's response.write is used to copy into DisabledDates array which is caught by javascript and forwarded to datepicker as below

```
<script>

    $(function() {

    var today = new Date()
    $('#simplest-usage').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    addDisabledDates: DisabledDays,
    maxPicks:1,
    altField: "#input_date"

    });
    });
    </script>
```

Doing all this results in dates from sql database automatically being blocked by datepicker  dynamically as in screenshot below

[Datepicker with Disabled Dates From database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMlH8.jpg)

This is for anyone who might find it useful , Thank you all